# For every game, is there a formula $f(G)$ which takes the game state $G$ as input and whose output can be interpreted as draw/win/lose?

Tags: game-theory

For the tic-tac-toe example, we may set the game state after a move by each player (X and O played), or equivalently before the move of the first player:

$M$ = \begin{bmatrix}M_{11}&M_{12}&M_{13}\\M_{21}&M_{22}&M_{23}\\M_{31}&M_{32}&M_{33}\end{bmatrix}

With $M_{ij}$ as 1 for the X's and -1 for the O's and 0 for no input.

In this case, is there a formula $f$ = $f(M)$ = $f(M_{ij})$ which can tell you if the game is winning, drawn or losing for the first player? As a false example, imagine if $det(M) < 0$ meant that the first player is losing, $det(M)=0$ that the game is drawn and $det(M)>0$ as a win for the starting player.

I would like to know if such as formula exists, which I suspect is true at least for a simple game such as tic-tac-toe, for more complicated games such as chess, and also if it is theoretically possible for any and all win/lose/draw games between two players.

What I am asking is distinct from a table-base lookup. I don't want to find a nifty way of encoding game states to an index in a theoretically computed table-base. I am asking if it is true that a theoretical formula exists for these games which only inputs the current game state and outputs something which can be interpreted as a win/draw/loss (if you want to be stricter, a function whose input game state cannot be solely determined by the output).

In the example of chess, I am asking if there is a theoretical function that can parse the encoded game state analytically (no looking ahead) and decide if the game is winning, losing or drawn.

In case I did not clarify well enough, I am willing to edit the question with your comments.

Comment: It seems very unlikely.  Look at [phutball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phutball#Computational_complexity)

Comment: Are you aware of Combinatorial Game Theory (JH Conway "On Numbers and games" etc https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_game_theory) for which there is now an extensive literature.

Comment: @saulspatz that looks like an interesting game. In general, does a problem being NP-complete mean there is no analytical formula (multiplication,a ddition, polynomials) to evaluate winning/losing?

Comment: @MarkBennet are you aware of any result which disproves the existence of such a no-look-ahead function as described? I am wondering about the connection with NP-complete problems. Initially I would say that NP-completeness would mean there can be no polynomial formula, since the computation would take O(1) time. Or is comparing the computation time of such a formula and the exhaustive search time of NP-complete problems like apples to oranges?

Comment: Couldn't it be that there is a problem where such a polynomial formula exists, but searching exhaustively is still an NP-complete problem and takes loads of time? Especially because the formula output tells you nothing of the sequence of moves you need to make to win.

Comment: NP-completeness relates to the complexity as the size of the game increases.  If $P\neq NP$, as is widely believed, then there is no polynomial function of $n$ that can compute mate-in-one on an $n\times n$ board.  However, I'm not sure that proves anything about a specific instance.  Suppose the function for an $n\times n$ board takes $O(C^{\log n})$ time to compute?  Does this meet your criterion or not?

Comment: No.  $NP$ doesn't require exhaustive search, just an algorithm for answering the question.

Comment: Since the formula I am looking for must work for any board state (i.e. cannot be taylored to a specific instance), I fear that means it cannot exist for NP-complete problems... it needs to be the same for any input, and output that the position is winning or losing. I was hoping that there is a trick to circumvent the NP-complete problem by not answering a specific move, but I guess it's over.

Comment: If the games are finite and have perfect information, there is, of course, the basic "exhaustive search" of the finite game tree. The point of the theory is to find means of efficient evaluation, to compare positions (which is better - ie who wins the difference) and to relax constraints to analyse a wider range of games (eg infinite game trees, loopy games where positions can recur etc). There are many NP-complete games. I would suggest you investigate the literature which is too extensive to be reduced to s short answer.

Comment: @MarkBennet what about the following: For a given number N, there exists an arrangement of logic gates with N inputs that outputs 1 if the input number (expressed in binary digits up to N digits) is prime and 0 if not prime. I can build this for any N. Why can I not build this (albeit much larger) to output 1 if a chess game is winning, if I find a way to encode the game state into binary inputs, for any valid combination of inputs?

Comment: How many gates would you need for chess? As I mentioned (provided threefold repetition is coded as an automatic draw, so there are no infinite loops) you can, in theory, code an exhaustive search for chess (exhaustive search for up to seven pieces is encoded already) - but could you do it with the material in the known universe?